# Elastic beanstalk : load balancer DNS unreachable

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, docker

I'm running a Django application with uWSGI inside a Docker container. This container is launched with Elastic Beanstalk from the CLI, it uses a load balancer (1 to 4 instances). I modified the nginx configuration in order to handle the SSL layer and the basic HTTP authentication, here is the start of the .ebextensions/01ssl.config content :

```
Resource  
sslSecurityGroupIngress: 
Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
Properties:
  GroupName: {Ref : AWSEBSecurityGroup}
  # GroupId: {Ref : AWSEBSecurityGroup}
  IpProtocol: tcp
  ToPort: 443
  FromPort: 443
  CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

files:
/etc/nginx/sites-available/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:
mode: "000644"
owner: root
group: root
content: |
  # HTTPS Server

  server {
    listen 443;
    server_name .mydomain.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://docker;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;

      proxy_set_header Connection "";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  }
```

The problem is that the application is reachable through the EC2 instance created by eb (ec2-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com) but not through the load balancer URL (foobar-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com). The SSL and authentication is correctly handled by nginx (the load balancer, right ?) when I access to the EC2 instance directly.
My goal is to use Route53 with this application but currently, it does not work if I specify the load balancer URL as stated by the documentation.
What did I miss ?

**EDIT 1**

Thank you Rico but unfortunately, it did not work, at least, it helped me dig into the permissions stuff. The TCP port 443 was already open to everyone on the EC2 instance (thanks to the first .ebextensions block).

If I add the secure port 443 with my certificate in *EB console > configuration > network tier > load balancing*, the health check URL is unreachable because there is a HTTP authentication (error 401, status check is red).

I  tried to create two servers in the nginx configuration, the first listens to the port 80 and always returns 200, the second one redirects to my application and handles the SSL and HTTP authentication stuff:

```
Resources:
sslSecurityGroupIngress: 
Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
Properties:
  GroupName: {Ref : AWSEBSecurityGroup}
  # GroupId: {Ref : AWSEBSecurityGroup}
  IpProtocol: tcp
  ToPort: 443
  FromPort: 443
  CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

files:
  /etc/nginx/sites-available/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:
mode: "000644"
owner: root
group: root
content: |
  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default         "upgrade";
        ""                      "";
  }

  server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
                 return 200 'OK';
        }
  }

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/docker_server.conf:
mode: "000644"
owner: root
group: root
content: |
  # HTTPS Server

  server {
    listen 443;
    server_name .example.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://docker;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;

      proxy_set_header Connection "";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  }
```

In this configuration, the second server is not reached even if I connect to *https://www.example.com.*, instead, I receive a 200 OK. How can I redirect to my application on the port 443?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200, it works.
Steps to reproduce :

- Use the file in the .ebextensions given in my first EDIT 1 block (you must provide the files .htpassword, server.crt and server.key too)
- Launch the Elastic Beanstalk environment
- Add a 443 listener to the load balancer with the following command:
  `aws elb create-load-balancer-listeners --load-balancer-name <my load balancer name> --listeners "Protocol=HTTPS,LoadBalancerPort=443,InstanceProtocol=HTTPS,InstancePort=443,SSLCertificateId=arn:aws:iam::<my uploaded certificate>"`
  (it does not work from *EB console > configuration > network tier > load balancing* because the loadbalancer port 443 is forwarded to the instance port 80)
- Edit the security group of the the load balancer (not the instance) and allow the HTTPS traffic (inbound and outbound)

The next steps for me are to create a script which automatically execute these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your not allowing your load balancer's security group into the EC2 instance's security group where your Beanstalk application is running.

You can see that the security group for your load balancer is `amazon-elb/amazon-elb-sg` if you're using EC2 classic. (If your are using VPCs then you need to use your specific LB security group for your VPC)

[image: sg1]

Then you can go to your instance's security group and add it:

[image: sg2]

In EC2 classic there's only one security group per account per region, so if you'd like more security you will need to use VPCs.